# How to get a value throughout my React Native Project

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am completely new to the RN.I have some parameters which are always changing but need to be used at several screens in my project(such as my local api ip changes depending on the router I am connected to, and several other ones). Please tell me a method to do so.
My project is in early stages, but I will be having a lot of screens by the end and the parameters would be needed in the almost all of them.

My current Screens Stack is:-

TabNavigator

- HomeStack

  - HomeScreen
  - RestaurantScreen
  - DetailScreen
- ProfileStack

  - UserScreen
  - ActivityScreen
  - PasswordScreen
- SettingsStack

  - SettingsScreen
  - InfoScreen
  - ContactScreen

The newer Screens would be added in the TabNavigator and a new Drawer will also be added, so just using screenProps will not work.

Please help me pass them

I have tried using a function component to pass the values, but they are passed as an object and I require them as string.

This is a function component I tried to pass

```
export default function GlobalParams (props){
    const url= "http://192.168.123.1:8000"
    return url
}
```

This is one of the screen where I tried to import the above stated function

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { FlatList,StyleSheet,View, Text } from "react-native";
import GlobalParams from "../../GlobalParams";

export default class RestaurantScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    path : '',
  };
  componentDidMount(){
    const url = <GlobalParams />
    this.setState({path: url.toString()+"/backend/restaurant"})
    fetch(this.state.path)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }))
      .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            console.log(this.state.path)
              throw error;
            });
  }
```

I am receiving the "GlobalParams" as "[object Object]" and hence not able to use the url.

So please help.

Comment: shouldn't it be `const url = GlobalParams()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a global configuration that might have a lot of variables that might be needed in different components and files, I would suggest the following approach.

```
const baseURL = 'http://192.168.40.108:4000';
const someOtherProperty = 'Some other value';

export {
    baseURL,
    someOtherProperty
}
```

Inside your component, you can then simply require the needed configuration such as follows:

```
import {baseURL, someOtherProperty} from './global';
```

You can then directly refer to these values inside your code.

**Of course, this might not be the safest approach for a production version, but this will work for flawlessly for your local environment as the application grows.**

Also, you do not need to `setState` after requiring the values, you can directly use them inside the `fetch` call. Setting the state will cause unnecessary re-renders.

```
fetch(`${baseURL}/resource/sub-resource`).then((res) => {
    //.... other operation
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to have a variable globally in your app. I think you only want to define some variables and use them in whole of your codes. If I guessed the first solution is far better to use. But if you want to define a variable and plus having that variable globally you want to change this variable in any component the second solution is what you desire.

1- You can use `global.variable` to define your variable and access it everywhere in your project. For example in your `App.js` file you can define your `URL` address as below:

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        global.URL='https://www.google.com';
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <View>
             <ChildComponent/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Now you have your URL parameter in your `ChildComponent`:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {

    render() {

    console.log('global.URL: ',global.URL);

        return (
            <View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

2- Using React Context: As I said before if you want to have a variable which is global and also can update your app by changing it you can use this method. I explain it briefly here but you can find a good documentation here https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html . A context could be simply defined as below:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();
```

Now if you want to use this parameter in a component you should use it as a provider:

```
class AppProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        number: 10,
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
            </AppContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Now in ChildComponent:

```
   class ChildComponent extends Component {

        render() {    
            return (
               <AppProvider> 
                <View>
                </View>
              </AppProvider> 
            );
        }
    }
```

Please vote me up it was helpful:)

Comment: But the baseUrl will be the same everywhere, there's no point manipulating it anywhere. Also, you can always import the default config and overwrite its values only if it's required.

Comment: yes that is quite right I just suggested this methods not only for base URl but also for all parameters that want to be global.

Answer (score 0):

**As you said parameters which are always changing . You can create a class and define global variables which will be accessed through out the app and with help of getter and setter functions you can get or update values**

**Create a Class DataHandler.js**

```
let url= "http://192.168.123.1:8000"

function setUrl(urlParam) {
  url = urlParam;
}

function getUrl() {
  return url;
}

export default {
  setUrl,
  getUrl
};
```

**Get Value**

```
import { getUrl } from './DataHandler';

......

componentDidMount() {
const url = DataHandler.getUrl()
}
```

**Set Value**

```
import { setUrl } from './DataHandler';

......

componentDidMount() {
DataHandler.setUrl("http://192.168.123.2:8000")
}
```